# JAXWS in Websphere

Tags: websphere, jax-ws

I wrote a simple Webservice as below in Netbeans.

```java
@WebService()
public class CRSEncryptString {

/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "encryptString")
public String encryptString(@WebParam(name = "plainText")
String plainText) {
    System.out.println("************* ");
    String cipher = plainText;
    System.out.println("***************************");
    return cipher;
}

}
```

Added jars with are related to **JAX-WS** like:
activation.jar,FastInfoset.jar,http.jar,jaxb jars, jaxws jars, saaj jars, etc

Its working fine in Tomcat and Weblogic.

But, while running in `Websphere 6.1` its giving error.

Following is serverlog:

```
[2/17/12 17:22:53:421 IST] 0000003c AdminHelper   A   ADMN1009I: An attempt is made to start the JAXWS-Test1_war application.
[2/17/12 17:22:54:390 IST] 0000003c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: JAXWS-Test1_war
[2/17/12 17:22:54:452 IST] 0000003c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: JAXWS-Test1_war  Application build level: Unknown
[2/17/12 17:22:54:624 IST] 0000003c WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: JAXWS-Test1.war.
[2/17/12 17:22:54:936 IST] 0000003c http          I   WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing

[2/17/12 17:22:55:264 IST] 0000003c http          E   WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.LinkageError: You are loading old SAAJ from jar:file:/E:/Program%20Files/Websphere6_1/lib/j2ee.jar!/javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory.class
                             java.lang.LinkageError: You are loading old SAAJ from jar:file:/E:/Program%20Files/Websphere6_1/lib/j2ee.jar!/javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory.class
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:184)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(SOAPVersion.java:83)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:177)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.BindingID.<clinit>(BindingID.java:318)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:177)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.createBinding(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:605)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:653)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:606)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:333)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:549)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1295)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1129)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:814)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:948)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:3731)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:3813)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:245)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1483)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:265)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1089)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:971)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DynamicMetaDataImpl.invoke(DynamicMetaDataImpl.java:231)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MetaDataImpl.invoke(MetaDataImpl.java:238)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:833)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1055)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:948)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:265)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1089)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:971)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DynamicMetaDataImpl.invoke(DynamicMetaDataImpl.java:231)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MetaDataImpl.invoke(MetaDataImpl.java:238)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:833)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1055)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:948)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:338)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:55)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:680)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:484)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1498)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/xml/soap/MessageFactory;
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:178)
    ... 78 more

[2/17/12 17:22:55:467 IST] 0000003c WebApp        E   WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.LinkageError: You are loading old SAAJ from jar:file:/E:/Program%20Files/Websphere6_1/lib/j2ee.jar!/javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory.class
 [2/17/12 17:22:55:514 IST] 0000003c ServletWrappe I   SRVE0242I: [JAXWS-Test1_war] [/JAXWS-Test1] [CRSEncryptString]: Initialization successful.
[2/17/12 17:22:55:530 IST] 0000003c VirtualHost   I   SRVE0250I: Web Module <null> has been bound to default_host[*:9080,*:80,*:9443,*:5060,*:5061,*:443].
[2/17/12 17:22:55:561 IST] 0000003c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0221I: Application started: JAXWS-Test1_war
[2/17/12 17:23:05:714 IST] 00000048 ServletWrappe I   SRVE0242I: [JAXWS-Test1_war] [/JAXWS-Test1] [/index.jsp]: Initialization successful.
```

Please suggest me further.

Thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the classloader policy of the Websphere through admin console, i.e, from Parent_first to Parent_last policy....

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think you're going to have difficulty with JAX-WS under WebSphere if you're not using WebSphere's own implementation. So you'll want to not deploy any extra jars but instead use the ones that are already in WebSphere 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RAD, you should add the Websphere Application Server runtime to your Project Build Path, instead of adding external jars.

Comment: Please can you suggest me the procedure of adding at runtime... It fits to my problem....

Comment: I don't have RAD at hand, but it's something like this: Right Click in your project -> Build Path-> Libraries and there you add IBM WAS Runtime to your project.

Answer (score 0):

It is risky to change the classloader order in Websphere since you are loading custom implementations which may not be supported by Websphere and you may get runtime errors like LinkageErrors and ClassCastException etc. since different implementations coexists in the same Java process. The best way is to use the IBM supported Jax-WS programming model.
Alternatively you can use a custom webservice engine by disabling IBM´s

-Dcom.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine=true